# How can I use differentFrom and sameAs in owlready2?

Tags: python, ontology, swrl, owlready

In Prótege software is able to insert the differentFrom and sameAs in SWRL Rules, but when I code these properties in Python with owlready2 imported I came across with below message:

```
semantic            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owlready2/rule.py", line 173, in _find_entity
semantic            |     raise ValueError("Cannot find entity '%s'!" % name)
semantic            | ValueError: Cannot find entity 'differentfrom'
```

Do you know how to use these properties correctly?

Comment: How do you use it. Please show the code. And it's `differentFrom` - it's case sensitive.